# .htaccess .php to htm

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi guys I want to rewrite all `.php` file to `.htm` instead.

I did this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$     $1.php    [QSA]
```

It doesn't work but when I type `.htm` it works but I want it to be automatically.

Can someone help me please.

Comment: @Prix 404 error. Thats what I got

Answer (score 0):

When the browser requests a URL, the webserver gets it, the hostname is removed and that is part of the request's URI.

- I request `http://example.com/foo/bar.php`
- Webserver gets it, and the URI is `/foo/bar.php`.

The rewrite engine takes the URI and **rewrites it** to another URL. Like so:

```
RewriteRule <from this URI> <to this URI>
```

If you want to be able to type `http://example.com/foo/bar.php` and have it internally rewritten to `/foo/bar.html` and have that resource get served in its place, you need:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ $1.htm  [L]
```